# Adding two complex numbers using java generics

Tags: java, generics

Below i have been given a class 'Fclass' according to which i have to create constructors and methods which i have done above the 'Fclass' but i am constantly getting error in the 'add' method in which i have to return sum of two complex numbers. Can someone please point out where am i going wrong? Format of returning value is '10.0 + 20.0i + 13.3 + 5.12i = 23.3 + 25.12i'

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ComplexNum<T>{
        T r;
        T i;
        public ComplexNum(T r2,T i2) {
            this.r = r2;
            this.i = i2;
        }
        
        public ComplexNum<Double> add(ComplexNum<Double> c2){
            ComplexNum<Double> res = new ComplexNum(r, i);
            res.r =  r +c2.r;
            res.i = i + c2.i
            return res;
            
            
        
            
        }
        public String toString() {
            return r + "+" + i + "i";
        }
            
        
        
    }
  
 class FClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n1, n2;
            double d1, d2;
            n1 = sc.nextInt();
            n2 = sc.nextInt();
            d1 = sc.nextDouble();
            d2 = sc.nextDouble();
            ComplexNum<Integer> c1 = new ComplexNum<Integer>(n1, n2);
            ComplexNum<Double> c2 = new ComplexNum<Double>(d1, d2);
            ComplexNum<Double> c3 = c1.add(c2);
            System.out.println(c1 + " + " + c2 + " = " + c3);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `res.r =  r +c2.r;` - r is of type `T`, which can be anything. How do you expect to use arithmetic operator on unknown type? Also why do you even use generics in the first place, if your add method uses the concrete `ComplexNum<Double>`, instead of the generic type you declated?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to constraint T to subtype of Number.  Number can be Integer or Double.  Only then, you can actually retrieve the values from r and i.

See below:

```
class ComplexNum < T extends Number > {
  private T r;
  private T i;
  
  public ComplexNum (T r2, T i2){
    this.r = r2;
    this.i = i2;
  }

  public ComplexNum < Double > add (ComplexNum < T > c){
    return new ComplexNum < Double > (
                  r.doubleValue () + c.r.doubleValue (),
                      i.doubleValue () + c.i.doubleValue ()
                  );
  }
  
  public String toString (){
    return r + "+" + i + "i";
  }
}

public class Main{
  public static void main (String[]args){
    ComplexNum < Integer > c1 = new ComplexNum <> (2, 3);
    ComplexNum < Integer > c2 = new ComplexNum <> (1, 2);
    ComplexNum < Double > c3 = c1.add (c2);
    System.out.println (c1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i understood where i was going wrong.